# How can i display the database data to an JTable(dynamic) in Swings?

Tags: java, hibernate, swing, jtable

We are using `hibernate` in business layer,but the  task is,
by using the `JTable` in `Swing` to display the dynamic data(`Swing`) from the database.
code:

```
    Criteria criteria=session.createCriteria(User.class);
    //here user.class is pojo class in hibernate.

    List studentlist= criteria.list();

    System.out.println("records"+studentlist);
    //here the data is showing in hibernate console, but how  to represent that data in the format of "jtable".
```

Answer (score 2):

We can retrieve a List of Objects from hibernate. To show the Objects in JTable, just inherited a class from AbstractTableModel and supply getRowCount() ,getColumnCount() and getValueAt() methods. And the getColumnName method is often need to be overrided to show the column name you want, not the X,Y,Z form.
Lets say You have a PERSON table in some database and its corresponding persistent class Person.

Source of PersonTableModel.java:

```
import org.hibernate.*;
import org.hibernate.cfg.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;



public class PersonTableModel extends AbstractTableModel
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6105842825518764825L;
    private ArrayList<Person> PersonList;

    public PersonTableModel()
    {
        super();
        SessionFactory sf=new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
        Session session=sf.openSession();

        Query q=session.createQuery("from Person");
        PersonList=new ArrayList<Person>(q.list());

        session.close();
        sf.close();
    }

    public int getRowCount()
    {
        return PersonList.size();
    }

    public int getColumnCount()
    {
        return 5;
    }

    public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex)
    {
        Person p=PersonList.get(rowIndex);
        Object[] values=new Object[]{p.getId(),p.getFirstname(),p.getLastname(),
                p.getAge(),p.getDescription()};
        return values[columnIndex];
    }

    @Override
    public String getColumnName(int column)
    {
        String[] columnNames=new String[]{"id","FirstName","LastName","Age","description"};
        return columnNames[column];
    }
}
```

Then create a PersonTableModel Object and set the JTable’s model to it

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you read the tutorial [How to use tables](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html), from Java.

If you have a more specific need, edit your question to add details.

Comment: +1, a link to a tutorial or a specific method is always appreciated. Not only does it provide information to this answer but it provides a resource for potential future problems.

Answer (score 1):

I've never used hibernate, but based on the code provided it looks like the data from your database is returned in a List. Therefore you will need to create a custom TableModel to access the data in the List.

The [BeanTableModel](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/27/bean-table-model/) might help you out.

Comment: +1 for adding more details and a possible solution (to a very unspecific question).

Comment: wat u r thinking is same to my requirements.but i cannot understand.can u send me the acutal code about that requirements.
like:
Criteria criteria=session.createCriteria(User.class);
   
  List studentlist= criteria.list();
//this studentlist can contains data(database).

String[] columnNames = {"EMPLOYEE NO","FULL NAME","USER","PASSWORDS","DEPARTMENTS","PHONE"};
//then how can i create rowdata?
//can u send me any code or suggestions.its urgent!

Comment: @harish - there is no "send me the code" solution to your problem, as we don't know your full requirements. Check the tutorial I gave in my answer, as it contains all information you will need to create and populate your JTable. It will require work from your side, it can't be answered in a few lines of code.